# What is the result of multiple, consecutive Select statements in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql

I have the following select statements in a T-SQL stored procedure.  What is the result of having multiple, consecutive select statements?  Are the results concatenated together?
Here is a few lines of the stored procedure.  Assume the variables are defined, etc.

```
Select @MaxEventId=Max(EventId) From Events Where ID=@Id
Select @LastEventId=EventDefId From Events Where Id=@Id and EventId=@MaxEventId 
Select @Redirect=Redirect From vEventStates Where EventStateId=@LastEventId and EventDefId=@LastEventId
```

Comment: your `select`s are just assigning values to the variables, nothing more

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, all of the selects will complete, and the proc will return a 0 value to whatever called it.

If you had multiple select statements that returned multiple rows each, instead of assigning values, then you would have multiple return sets returned.

If your application is not expecting multiple data sets to be returned, it will probably accept the first set and continue running as if the proc was done.